# How to delay an if-else execution in Kotlin (Android Studio) which is already inside a runnable?

Tags: android, kotlin, delay, runnable

I need to delay the execution of an  if-else statement which is already inside a runnable, for 4 seconds.

Since, it is already inside a runnable, I don't know how to delay it.

runnable= object:Runnable{

```
        override fun run() {
            num1= random.nextInt(99-0)
            num2= random.nextInt(99-0)
            resultNum=num1+num2
            randomView.text="$num1 + $num2"


            num= typeView.text.toString().toInt()
```

//Need a 4 second delay here.

```
                if(num==resultNum)
                {
                    score++
                    scoreView.text="Score: $score"
                }
                else
                {
                    scoreView.text="Score: $score"
                }

                typeView.text=""
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay)
        }
    }
    handler.post(runnable)
```

I expect the if-else to delay for 4 seconds.

Comment: Please take a look https://jamie.mccrindle.org/posts/exploring-kotlin-standard-library-part-3/

Comment: you can call another runnable with 4 second delay with handler.postDelayed inside your runnable